# How to add a comment to Gradle's eclipse task's classpath

Tags: xml, eclipse, groovy, gradle

Since the Gradle eclipse plugin creates a .classpath file with absolute paths to $HOME, I don't want people to commit it to the VCS. I already have a hook in place that will reject commits that have the text "dontCommit". I'd like to add a  comment to the generated .classpath XML file.

I've tried these with no success in my `eclipse.classpath.withXml` closure:

```
def root = it.asNode()
root.children()[0].appendNode(org.w3c.dom.Node.COMMENT_NODE, "dontCommit")
```

This uses the COMMENT_NODE's position in the enum as the element name, e.g., `<8>dontCommit</8>`.

```
it.asString() =~ "/(<classpath>)/<classpath> <!-- dontCommit -->/"
```

This is ugly (working with a regex on XML) and does not work; probably the string is not mapped back to XML. (Can't blame it for that...)

```
root.children()[0].appendNode("<!--", "dontCommit")
```

This creates `<<!-->dontCommit</<!-->`, i.e., invalid XML.

http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/Node.html#plus%28groovy.lang.Closure%29 says that I can use a Closure and builder style notation, but when I use the mkp prefix, I get a compiler error.

```
root.children()[0].plus {
    mkp.comment("dontCommit")
}
```

gets `No such property: mkp for class: org.gradle.api.internal.xml.XmlTransformer$XmlProviderImpl`

```
root.classpathentry.add(0, {
    mkp.comment("dontCommit)
})
```

compiles but does not seem to do anything.

How do I add that comment?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround: Eclipse conveniently ignores unknown tags, so I can add my marker in a dummy node like this:

```
it.asNode().appendNode("eclipse-ignore-this", "dontCommit")
```

(With added check that such a marker does not exist yet to not inflate the file for no reason.)